# Js reference is not loading correctly in Angular 6 application

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angular6

I have developed a Angular 6 based web application. But I am facing problem of loading js files correctly. I have deployed the site in firebase hosting (https://dishari-d2728.firebaseapp.com/).

Interesting thing is when I visit first time all JS loads correctly but if I visit another page and again return to homepage, JS files is not working, and If I refresh several time everything is loaded correctly. This is why I can't figure out where the actual problem is. I have referenced the JS files in the following way:

1. adding js files in the assets folder
2. register in the `angular.json`
3. loaded the script in `appcomponent.ts` files using `$GetScript()` function...

Comment: This is how single page applications work

Comment: Why are you loading scripts via Step #3? It appears that those files are being loaded after your `scripts.64fdf3b213b208706924.js` file which has dependencies on some of those assets. Have you tried to put those dependencies in your `angular.json` file or `index.html` file (before the Angular script file is injected) instead?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Dear @DanielWStrimpel, I have tried your suggested method too but did not work